# What Packages needs to be downloaded for using Support.PageObjects

Tags: user-interface, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, getelementbyid

I have to use [FindsBy(How=How. <>], but for this i need to include the namespace Support.PageObjects, which is currently showing the Red swiggly line. Which nuget package to download or assembly to refer to resolve this issue?